# Authentication with Owin and SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, owin

I have an application based on Owin authentication and I need to merge this login system with a SharePoint app. Any idea?

Comment: For anybody still looking for the answer, consider [SharePoint AspNet Authentication](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/SharePoint-AspNet-Authentication)